# Using the "System" database on Postgis -> ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis

I've been evaluating ArcGIS at work as a possible sollution to working with some .kmv files coming from a supplier that seems to be incompatible with QGIS. QGIS thinks they are corrupt, I suspect due to invalid unicode in xml name attributes. Different problem for a different time.

The problem I'm having is that whilst ArcGIS opens these fellas, we cant connect to our PostGIS database because for some reason that predates me (An earlier "NoSQL" dev that genuinely didnt seem to understand Postgres) our tables are stored in the system "postgres" database. We could change this, but it would involve a fairly serious chunk of engineering against the rest of the stack and I doubt I could get permission to do this just to open a few maps.

The  ArcGIS software just straight up tells us that we cant use that database and when I try to look up help, it just states that we dont need to do that. Actually I *do* need to do that.

I've tried seeing if I could get into the .sds definition file, but its a big fat binary blob and I havent found an editor around that would let me modify it.

Is there a way around this? Its got me stumped.

update:
Its Postgres 11.15 in the form of Azure's hosted postgres, with the Postgis and timescaledb (We do a lot of time series stuff too, IOT stuff)
As for ArcGIS Pro version, I *think* its 3.0. Latest version. I'm not in the office today so I'll check at a later point.

Comment: SOME degree of solution in using pg_featureserv , it can at least read off postgres, but I haven't manage to divine as to whether I can write off it, and I'd be turbo-worried about putting pg_featureserv anywhere near a public facing server :/

Comment: Please give the versions of your software/db.There were some changes at Postgres 12. https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/windows/database-requirements-postgresql.htm

Comment: Its Postgres 11.15 in the form of Azure's hosted postgres, with the Postgis and timescaledb (We do a lot of time series stuff too, IOT stuff)
As for ArcGIS Pro version, I *think* its 3.0. Latest version. I'm not in the office today so I'll check at a later point. (Also updated post)